# transform JSON to JSON ascending by date field xslt

Tags: json, xslt

I have below input json message.

```
{"transactions": [
      {
      "transactionEffectiveDate": "2011-10-20",
      "transactionCode": "310",
      "transactionDescription": "New Note",
      "transactionAmount": "0.00",
      "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
      "reversalFlag": false
   },
      {
      "transactionEffectiveDate": "2016-12-20",
      "transactionCode": "618",
      "transactionDescription": "Payment",
      "transactionAmount": "218.36",
      "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
      "reversalFlag": false
  },
      {
      "transactionEffectiveDate": "2010-02-20",
      "transactionCode": "618",
      "transactionDescription": "Payment",
      "transactionAmount": "238.83",
      "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
      "reversalFlag": false
   }
]}
```

Expected output: Sort the groups in ascending order by transactionEffectiveDate value.

```
{"transactions": [
{
      "transactionEffectiveDate": "2010-02-20",
      "transactionCode": "618",
      "transactionDescription": "Payment",
      "transactionAmount": "238.83",
      "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
      "reversalFlag": false
   }
      {
      "transactionEffectiveDate": "2011-10-20",
      "transactionCode": "310",
      "transactionDescription": "New Note",
      "transactionAmount": "0.00",
      "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
      "reversalFlag": false
   },
      {
      "transactionEffectiveDate": "2016-12-20",
      "transactionCode": "618",
      "transactionDescription": "Payment",
      "transactionAmount": "218.36",
      "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
      "reversalFlag": false
  },

]}
```

I am new to json transformation. Need to copy input to output but change order by effectivedate. example output posted below.I have tried with below xslt.getting parsing error. please help.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"> 

                        <xsl:template match='/ | @* | node()'>
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select='* | @* | node()' />
                            </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:template>

                        <xsl:template match="/"> 
  <xsl:for-each select="transactions"> 
    <xsl:sort select="transactionEffectiveDate" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
                    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Only XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 can represent JSON values as XDM values (i.e. JSON objects as XDM maps and JSON arrays as XDM arrays), if you have access to Saxon 9.8 PE or EE or Altova 2017 or 2018 with support for the higher-order function `array:sort` you can use a single XPath expression to create a new map with a sorted array:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="json" as="xs:string">
        {"transactions": [
        {
        "transactionEffectiveDate": "2011-10-20",
        "transactionCode": "310",
        "transactionDescription": "New Note",
        "transactionAmount": "0.00",
        "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
        "reversalFlag": false
        },
        {
        "transactionEffectiveDate": "2016-12-20",
        "transactionCode": "618",
        "transactionDescription": "Payment",
        "transactionAmount": "218.36",
        "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
        "reversalFlag": false
        },
        {
        "transactionEffectiveDate": "2010-02-20",
        "transactionCode": "618",
        "transactionDescription": "Payment",
        "transactionAmount": "238.83",
        "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
        "reversalFlag": false
        }
        ]}
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:sequence select="let $json-map := parse-json($json)
            return map { 'transactions' : array:sort($json-map?transactions, (), function($a) { $a?transactionEffectiveDate }) }"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Without higher-order functions (i.e. Saxon 9.8 HE) you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math array map mf"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="json" as="xs:string">
        {"transactions": [
        {
        "transactionEffectiveDate": "2011-10-20",
        "transactionCode": "310",
        "transactionDescription": "New Note",
        "transactionAmount": "0.00",
        "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
        "reversalFlag": false
        },
        {
        "transactionEffectiveDate": "2016-12-20",
        "transactionCode": "618",
        "transactionDescription": "Payment",
        "transactionAmount": "218.36",
        "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
        "reversalFlag": false
        },
        {
        "transactionEffectiveDate": "2010-02-20",
        "transactionCode": "618",
        "transactionDescription": "Payment",
        "transactionAmount": "238.83",
        "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
        "reversalFlag": false
        }
        ]}
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:function name="mf:array-sort" as="array(*)">
        <xsl:param name="array" as="array(*)"/>
        <xsl:param name="sort-key" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="sorted-items" as="item()*">
            <xsl:perform-sort select="$array?*">
                <xsl:sort select="map:get(., $sort-key)"/>
            </xsl:perform-sort>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="array {$sorted-items }"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:sequence select="let $json-map := parse-json($json)
            return map { 'transactions' : mf:array-sort($json-map?transactions, 'transactionEffectiveDate') }"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyQ.

If you want a transformation with templates then one way is to use `json-to-xml` to convert the JSON to an XML document, transform that with normal templates and convert it back to JSON using `xml-to-json`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="json" as="xs:string">
        {"transactions": [
        {
        "transactionEffectiveDate": "2011-10-20",
        "transactionCode": "310",
        "transactionDescription": "New Note",
        "transactionAmount": "0.00",
        "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
        "reversalFlag": false
        },
        {
        "transactionEffectiveDate": "2016-12-20",
        "transactionCode": "618",
        "transactionDescription": "Payment",
        "transactionAmount": "218.36",
        "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
        "reversalFlag": false
        },
        {
        "transactionEffectiveDate": "2010-02-20",
        "transactionCode": "618",
        "transactionDescription": "Payment",
        "transactionAmount": "238.83",
        "transactionSequenceNumber": "1",
        "reversalFlag": false
        }
        ]}
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:variable name="transformed-json-doc">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml($json)/node()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:message select="$transformed-json-doc"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="parse-json(xml-to-json($transformed-json-doc))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="array[@key = 'transactions']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
                <xsl:sort select="string[@key = 'transactionEffectiveDate']"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyQ/1